# Adding Block in existing module of magento

Tags: magento

I have customized customer module to meet my requirement. I am able to rewrite block classes of customer module. I am trying to add one custom block class in this module which is not exists in existing customer module but I don't know how to accomplish this.

my code looks like in config.xml

```
 <blocks>            
        <customer>
           <rewrite>                          
<widget_name>Mynamespace_Customer_Block_Widget_Name</widget_name>                   
<form_register>Mynamespace_Customer_Block_Form_Register</form_register>
<form_edit>Mynamespace_Customer_Block_Form_Edit</form_edit>
           </rewrite>                   
        </customer>  

     </blocks>
```

I created a new block class under the Form directory of customer module called 'Test.php'

And customer layout file looks like

```
<reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="customer/form_test" name="customer_test" template="customer/form/test.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```

But it is not executing the block class file. 
Is there anything should be added in config.xml file of this module?

Please help how this block can be integrated with existing module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't really be adding blocks to the customer module, you should be adding them to your own module. If you want to keep on w/ the customer module, check to make sure that your block is named as `Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Test` and extends `Mage_Core_Block_Template`. Otherwise, create the class as `Mynamespace_Customer_Block_Form_Test` and keep it in your module directory. Then, add a block definition for your class in `config.xml`:

```
<blocks>
  <mynamespace_customer>
    <class>Mynamespace_Customer_Block</class>
  </mynamespace_customer> 
</blocks>
```

Then you should be able to load the block as `mynamespace_customer/form_test`.

It may be easier to debug your problem if you use a module name *other than* customer. Generally speaking, that is a bad idea and will likely cause bugs in the system.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thank you very much joe, It worked I added the <class>Mynamespace_Customer_Block</class> just above the opening rewrite tag and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may already be aware of this but think about checking [LayoutViewer](http://alanstorm.com/2005/projects/MagentoLayoutViewer.tar.gz) to see what the layout thinks it is using.

Although I'm sure your example config.xml is just an example please make sure that you've remembered to create a rewrite for `form_test` and that there is a valid blocks section for your own module.

<sub>*BTW, LayoutViewer could really do with being packaged properly for Magento Connect. The linked file lacks the necessary config to enable the module and it would be much more useful if accessible from PEAR.*</sub>